# Custom expandable list view with child search filter

Tags: android, filter, expandablelistview

I've already implemented a list view with search filter but right now, I have to changed it to expandable list view with child search filter. There would be an edit text as a search bar and filters all the child of all groups. This is the scenario,

*Person - object consist of name, address, phone number and photo.

Group 1 - Friends (Child 1 - Person, Child 2 - Person, Child 3 - Person)

Group 2 - Family (Child 1 - Person, Child 2 - Person)

Group 3 - Officemates (Child 1 - Person, Child 2 - Person, Child 3 - Person, Child 4 - Person)

As of now, I have to port from array adapter to base expandable list adapter and filterable. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
edit.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

---

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {  

    } 

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {  

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        ((Filterable) ((ListAdapter) Adapter)).getFilter().filter(edit.getText().toString());
    }  
};
```

---

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter  implements Filterable {
    public void notifyDataSetInvalidated() {
        super.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null)
            filter = new MangaNameFilter();
            return filter;
        }
```

---

```
private class MangaNameFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        // NOTE: this function is *always* called from a background thread, and
        // not the UI thread.
        constraint = edit.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
            detailsList = detailsSer.GetAlldetails();
            dupCatList = detailsList;

            ArrayList<detailsEntity> filt = new ArrayList<detailsEntity>();
            ArrayList<detailsEntity> lItems = new ArrayList<detailsEntity>();
            synchronized(this) {
                lItems.addAll(dupCatList);
            }

            for(int i = 0, l = lItems.size(); i < l; i++) {
                detailsEntity m = lItems.get(i);

                if (m.description.toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                    filt.add(m);
                }

                result.count = filt.size();
                result.values = filt;
            } else {
                detailsList = detailsSer.GetAlldetails();
                dupCatList = detailsList;
                synchronized(this) {
                    result.count = dupCatList.size();
                    result.values = dupCatList;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults result) {
            // NOTE: this function is *always* called from the UI thread.

            filtered = (ArrayList<detailsEntity>)result.values;

            ArrayList<Integer> IdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            IdList.clear();
            for(int i = 0; i < filtered.size(); i++) {
                IdList.add(filtered.get(i).catID);
            }

            HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<Integer>(IdList);
            midList = new ArrayList<Integer>(hashSet) ;
            Collections.sort(midList);
            Adapter = new CategoryListAdapter(context, R.layout.list1, R.layout.list2, filtered, midList);
            List.setAdapter(Adapter);
        }
    }                   
}
```

Comment: can you explain little bit how i can implement this solution. hanks