# How to implement Custom ExpandableListView with filter?

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I have a custom Expandable list adapter with cursor group elements and array child elements. I need to implement filter option . I went through [Custom expandable list view with child search filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775774/custom-expandable-list-view-with-child-search-filter) but I could not understand what the MangaNameFilter class in there actually does .Pls suggest some basic steps. Any help woulb be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you call adapter.getFilter().filter() you in performFiltering() that handle filtered char sequence.

And dont forget to override getFilter() with instance of class `YourFilter extends Filter`

But another advise:
Dont use filters just add textwatcher with sql request.